# Tool to run a not-so-old PC game on Windows 10?

Tags: software-development, game, emulator

There is an old PC game called SubTerra( [SubTerra game link](http://crystalshard.net/?g=2) ). It used to run perfectly on Windows XP but fails to do so in Windows 10. Compatibility troubleshooter also didn’t help. DOSbox cannot emulate this game.

Any suggestions for tools to run this game smoothly on Windows 10?

Comment: Welcome to this site. Your question does not ask for software, which makes it off-topic for this site. Can you either [edit] that in (and tell us what you are willing to pay), *or* remove the question and place it on [SU]?

Comment: I've just slightly modified your question to fit this site while keeping your intention. Please [edit] it once more and add your "price tag": must it be free-of-charge, or is there some budget you'd be willing to spend if needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest trying running it on XP running in Virtual Box - you will need:

- either a copy of an XP disk or an ISO image of XP - you used to be able to download the latter from the MS site but it is no longer available.
- [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) *you could use VMWare but since that is charged for and Virtual Box is free...*
- A reasonable specification machine *which can even be running Linux*.

The steps are:

1. Install Virtual Box
2. Create a new VM
3. Install XP onto the VM
4. Install your game(s) onto the VM
5. Take a "Snapshot" that you can revert to

Comment: @SteveBarnes Thanks for your help, but is there any emulator kind of thing to run old softwares in fullscreen, rather than using a virtual machine ?

Comment: You can run a vm full screen. Graphics acceleration would be an issue.

Comment: @archity - If you were running Linux you could try Wine and there are some emulators about but MS were always cagey about some of the XP API and many games have never been supported by emulators so you are normally better off with a full VM.

Answer (score 0):

Some editions of Windows 10, such as Pro, come with Microsoft Hyper-V virtualization software. If you have one of these editions, you can install Hyper-V by right-clicking Start, choosing "Programs and Features" at the top, then clicking "Turn Windows features on or off" in the right sidebar.

Once you have Hyper-V installed, and you have restarted your computer, you can create a virtual machine and install Windows XP on it. Or you might try Windows 7 in your VM, and see if that will let you run your game.

If you don't have W10 Pro, you could try upgrading. I just checked, and my cost to upgrade W10 Home to W10 Pro would currently be $99.99 US. Not sure if that's something you're willing to consider or not.

Hyper-V *might* *possibly* have better support for graphics acceleration than VirtualBox or some of the other alternatives. I can't say for sure, though.